# Flyway and Jenkins integration using location from github path

Tags: jenkins, github, flyway

I want to integrate Jenkins and Flyway, and I did it successfully but now instead of choosing flyway scripts from /sql path, i want to look scripts from github path and then run flyway on that.
Any help would be appreaciable

Comment: Can you show how you’re calling Flyway from Jenkins? Are you using the command line? If so, can you show the parameters you’re passing in?

Comment: Hi @DavidAtkinson,    Thanks for reply !  I think Jenkins configuration is correct, if I am putting my scripts in file:///users/vikaspuri/.jenkins/tools/sp.sd.flywayrunner.installation.FlywayInstallation/flyway/sql/, then it is running perfect with Job, but now I want to change the location so in location parameter of Jenkin, I am setting filesystem:https://github.com/vikaspuri1886/Mulesoft/tree/master/src/main/resources/db/migration

Comment: I'm a little confused. The Jenkins job or pipeline should be where you specify your git repository. Once you've done this, you can use flyway.locations to specify the path to your migrations folder relative to the root of your git checkout folder.

Comment: Hi @DavidAtkinson, Thanks for your response. I resolved this issue by making job which will first fetch data or checkout from github then copy the scripts in flyway/sql location which worked fine for me.

Comment: Yes. This is the conventional approach to using such tools. Glad you got it working. I’d recommend you take a look at using a Jenkinsfile (pipeline as code) if you’re starting out as it is likely to become how most pipelines are handled in the future.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [flyway documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/locations) it supports the following migration locations:

- Classpath
- Filesystem
- Amazon S3
- Google Cloud Storage